# Moving an element in the documents causes scroll to reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple "popup" windows implemented as divs. When a user clicks on one div I will place that div at the end of the body `$(body).append(this.popContainer)` or module container `$(me.parentContainer).append($(this));`. The problem is that the scroll position is reset when I do this.

This is so I can assure the popup is on top of all the others. I could mess with the z-index but many elements in the page are modules that have behavior and html, they can be moved around the document or placed somewhere else.

The modules do not know about other modules but to implement z-index correctly the modules have to know about all the other elements in the page to make sure they stack correctly.

To move floating modules forward (top of the stack) I would like to continue using something like `$(this.container).append(this.subElemnt)`.

So the question is: Is there a way to reflow the document elements without using z-index and without having the scroll position reset?

It can be a jQuery solution or any other library.

Here is the example code https://jsfiddle.net/gsrLs671/ (scroll and click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this where you are looking for? It's keeping the current position of the scrollbars.

```js
var incrementalid = 0;

function container(config) {
  var colors = ["yellow", "red"],
    addHandlers,
    blocks = [undefined, undefined].map((none, index) => {
      incrementalid++;
      return block({
        color: colors[index]
      });
    });
  var container = $("<div></div>");
  container.css({
    position: "absolute",
    width: "150px",
    backgroundColor: config.color,
    height: "150px",
    top: config.pos + "px",
    left: config.pos + "px",
    overflow: "scroll"
  });
  container[0].id = incrementalid;
  addHandlers = (function(id) {
    return function() {
      console.log("this is addhandler:", $("#" + id), id);

      $("#" + id).off("click.moveUp").on("click.moveUp", function() {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        var scrollLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();      
        $("#hi").append($(this));           
        $(this).scrollTop( scrollTop ).scrollLeft( scrollLeft );
        addHandlers();
      });
    }
  }(incrementalid))
  incrementalid++;
  container.append(blocks);
  $("#hi").append(container);
  addHandlers();
};

function block(config) {
  var block = $("<div></div>");
  block[0].id = incrementalid;
  block.css({
    position: "absolute",
    width: "60px",
    height: "60px",
    backgroundColor: config.color,
    top: (60 * incrementalid) + "px",
    left: (60 * incrementalid) + "px"
  });
  return block;
};

container({
  pos: 30,
  color: "blue"
});
container({
  pos: -10,
  color: "green"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hi" style="position:relative">

</div>
```